# CakePHP 3: Unable to insert fixtures when running phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I just baked some Fixtures and some TestCases and whenever I run `vendor/bin/phpunit` I get a version of the following error:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 4.7.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

IException: Unable to insert fixtures for "App\Test\TestCase\Controller\ScreensControllerTest" test case. SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureManager.php, line 254]
```

The fixtures and tests were baked automatically using the bake tools. I checked that each item in the `$fixtures` property corresponds to a file in `tests/Fixture/`. If I comment out the `$fixtures` declaration in any of the test classes the error just moves to the next class. So it's not bad syntax in any specific fixture/test.

Comment: Can you try re-baking everything? Especially with sudo priveleges

Comment: @UnstableEagle I already rebaked each fixture and table test and the problem persists. However I didn't use sudo. Are you thinking this is a permissions issue?

Comment: I think it would be a good place to start. I think the issue might be that PHP cannot get at the folder/directory that its requesting because Linux might be locking PHP out

Comment: @UnstableEagle I rebaked the Fixture with `sudo` and the error remains the same, even if I run phpunit with `sudo`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error means that PHP is not able to connect to the database. If you are using a SQLite database, make sure the directory is writable and exists.

Comment: Bingo. Problem with the datasource configs!